# How do I use Wine and Bottles simultaneously?

Tags: 22.04

I need to test if a Windows application's error is related with Wine or with Bottles, right now the error appears with Bottles.

Is there a way to have Wine and Bottles installed so that they do not disturb each other?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Bottles is a Wine prefix manager meaning that all you need to do is right click on the app and press `"run with wine"`

Note: The Bottles developers strongly recommend that users install Bottles through Flatpak as it is used for sandboxing.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the main post. Must I choose "sys-wine-9.0"? I could not find "run with wine". I have installed Bottles through Flatpak.

Comment: With "sys-wine-9.0" the same error as with soda option. Perhaps I still must install the latest vanilla wine separately?